# how can I create a css double line-through in ie 11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I would like to create a double line-through in IE11, but I'm having some trouble. It seems that the text-decoration is limited in IE11. Currently I'm using a single line, but since we will use some kanji it may be confused as part of the kanji itself: a double line would be better.

```
*.strike {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You should post an image of how the double line will look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positioned pseudo-element

```css
span.double-strike {
  position: relative;
}

span.double-strike:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span>
  This is my text with <span class="double-strike">
two lines through it</span> in a paragraph because of crazy weird
<span class="double-strike">requirements</span>
</span>
```

Note with this option each strike can have a different color...as an added *bonus*.

Answer (score 0):

IE11 does not natively support this...

However there is a potential hacky option... you can always do something like this...

Set a span around the text you wish to apply a double strike through on and then absolutely position the strike through on top of the text.

Found an example on JS Fiddle that shows you what I'm talking about.

```
span.double-strike {
  position: relative;
}

span.double-strike div.the-lines {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px; /* Depends on the font size */
   left: 0;
   border-top: 3px double black;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmcculloh/Ud5L4/

Comment: Here is the report for IE11 - https://caniuse.com/#feat=text-decoration

Comment: I found this solution as well, but for the current project I'm working on it's a bit too elaborate to integrate. I was hoping for an easier way to do this. Thanks anyway.